# Как узнать адрес текущей страницы сайта из ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript

Добрый день! Как узнать адрес текущей страницы сайта из ActionScript 3? Имеется ввиду не путь к файлу, а именно адрес в строке браузера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если браузер позволяет запускать яваскрипт:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available)
{
   var urle:String =    ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает. Можно еще один вопрос: как тоже самое можно сделать на ActionScript 2 ?

Comment: без понятия

не забываем плюсовать ответ

Comment: В ActionScript 2 - это тоже работает, все OK !!!